# Render FBO to screen taking into account Depth

Tags: opengl-es, depth-buffer

Target: OpenGL ES 3.0

Suppose my default Framebuffer (the screen) already contains part of my scene rendered; its color and depth buffers contain valid data.

Now suppose I have another part of the scene rendered to an intermediate FBO 'fbo1' already. Its color data is kept in texture 'mColor', which is attached to fbo1.COLOR0 attachment, and its depth is kept in another texture 'mDepth', which is attached to the DEPTH attachment of yet another FBO 'fbo2'.

Now I would like to take mColor and render it to the Screen, taking into account the depth from mDepth. I know how to render a texture containing only color data to the screen, but I don't know how to do so taking into account the mDepth.

Essentially it looks like when we render the Quad textured with mColor to the screen, we need to compare the Screen's depth buffer not with the depth from the Quad, but with depth from mDepth. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are splitting your pipeline and rendering FBO0 in multiple passes interleaved with off-screen rendering then the simple answer is "you're doing it wrong".

You're forcing the GPU to write out and read-back your intermediate states which is horribly inefficient, in particular on mobile with tile-based architectures.

Render each off-screen pass first, and then render the window surface (FBO0) to completion in a single pass.

> We need to compare the Screen's depth buffer not with the depth from the Quad, but with depth from mDepth. How to do that?

Load the depth value from the depth texture, and assign that value to `gl_FragDepth` in your fragment shaders. However this will force all of your fragments to a late-zs depth update, which is horribly slow compared to using the real triangle z-value at early-zs as you have to run the shader before you determine if you need to keep the fragment or not. So, as per the above I'd suggest redesigning your rendering pipeline so you don't need to do this ...

Comment: I see. 

Here's what I am really doing: first I render most of my scene. Then, in N passes, I render each object that needs some postprocessing to a offscreen buffer. I calculate where the object will end up on the screen (its Mesh is quite simple), render it to a FBO just big enough, then I apply post-processing to the object, and then I face the problem described in the question: how to merge this to the screen.
I thought it would be simpler to post-process per-object, because this way if I, for instance, BLUR the object I don't have to worry about closer objects 'creeping' into my BLUR.

Comment: Blur naturally implies some form of "fuzzy edge" - that's half the point of it - so at some point you're going to have to resolve the "creep" anyway. You're just postponing the pain to a later point in the pipeline, you've not made it go away.

Comment: No no, I've implemented your suggestion and it works perfectly - i.e. if we have a closer, unblurred object partially obstructing a further, blurred object, the closer one stays perfectly sharp. To achieve this effect without per-object post-processing (i.e. if I had to post-process the whole scene in one go) I'd have to use stencil to mark the further object, then apply blur with stencil test, BUT taking into account the DEPTH (pixels of the further object that are near to the border with the closer object cannot get influenced by the pixels of the closer object! ).

Comment: Even if I took into account the DEPTH and stopped blurring exactly when the first pixel of the 'closer' object appears, the effect would not be the same - I'd never be able to influence those blurred pixels by that part of the further object, that is obstructed, so when the two objects move around, the blur would unnaturally change near the border between the objects.

Answer (score 1):

You could use your FBO's depth as a texture. When you draw the FBO's content, you draw the color pass and write gl_FragDepth manually from the FBO's depth texture. After that you can draw all your other scene content with proper depth test enabled.

Comment: Hmm... I dont quite understand. Of course, when I am rendering a Quad textured with mColor to the screen, in my fragment shader I can write to gl_FragDepth and set it to contents of 'mDepth', but that doesn't give me anything. The DEPTH test has already run before the fragment shader and has compared screen's depth with Depth gotten from linear interpolation of the Quad's 4 corners, rather than with mDepth. This is the problem.